# How to retrieve object type properties from RDF using SPARQL queries?

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, object-property

I have created a simple ontology using Protege and now I want to retrieve data from the RDF file of that ontology. I have an object property like below:

```
<JavaOntology:sameQuestionAs rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/jeny/ontologies/2018/8/JavaOntology#What_is_the_purpose_of_Class_in_java"/>
```

I want to retrieve only the part after `#`. For example, I want the output as `What_is_the_purpose_of_Class_in_java`. But when I receive the RDF file I get the output as this

```
http://www.semanticweb.org/jeny/ontologies/2018/8/JavaOntology#What_is_the_purpose_of_Class_in_java
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Actually, the "correct" way would be to add additional data providing the human-readable form of the RDF/OWL entities. This is best practice. For example, mostly `rdfs:label` is used for this. In Protege this is done via the annotations.

Comment: can you please provide an example query for that.

Comment: If you really want to use SPARQL, you have to use string modifications - which is actually weird, because it shouldn't be necessary in a perfect world - but to some extend possible. `prefix ex: <http://www.semanticweb.org/jeny/ontologies/2018/8/JavaOntology#> select ?name {?s ?p ?o. bind(strafter(str(?o),str(ex:)) as ?name)}` is the common way to do it. Indeed, you have to adapt it to your query which you didn't show here, so I can only show it for a generic query.

Comment: By the way, you question title is totally misleading...I don't what this has to do with *"retrieve object properties from RDF ... "*

Comment: thanks @AKSW it worked and sorry if it is misleading. I am a beginner in this area

Comment: Ok, then please provide the working query as an answer here and click on accept such others can see this question was solved. Thanks